# Request signature does not match signature provided for Amazon AWS using Python

Tags: python, python-requests, amazon-product-api

So I'm attempting to collect reviews from Amazon using their API. Unfortunately though it seems that I might be doing something wrong at some point in my program. It's sending back a response that many others were apparently getting. Believe me, I've gone through and looked and everyone elses questions and nothing has worked. Please help me.

Here's the code:

```
__author__ = 'dperkins'

import requests
import amazonproduct
import time
import datetime
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import urllib
import ssl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Configuration for the AWS credentials
config = {
    'access_key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'secret_key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'associate_tag': 'dperkgithu-20',
    'locale': 'us'
}
api = amazonproduct.API(cfg=config)

productASIN = ''
productTitle = ''

# Product look up for the official iPhone 5s White 16gb Unlocked
for product in api.item_search('Electronics', Keywords='iPhone'):
    if product .ASIN == 'B00F3J4E5U':
        productTitle = product.ItemAttributes.Title
        productASIN = product.ASIN

# Product Title with ASIN and a formatted underline
print productTitle + ': ' + productASIN

underline = ''
for int in range(len(productTitle + ': ' + productASIN)):
    underline += '-'
print underline

# URL First portion of the request for reviews
signatureTime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", time.gmtime())
signatureTime = urllib.quote_plus(signatureTime)    # Must url encode the timestamp
url = "http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Reviews&IdType=ASIN&ItemId=%s&AssociateTag=%s&AWSAccessKeyId=%s&Timestamp=%s" % (productASIN, api.associate_tag, api.access_key, signatureTime)

# # HMAC with SHA256 hash algorithm
# dig = hmac.new(api.secret_key, msg=url, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
# signature = base64.b64encode(dig).decode()      # py3k-mode

#url = 'http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Reviews&IdType=ASIN&ItemId=%s&AssociateTag=%s&AWSAccessKeyId=%s&Timestamp=%s&Signature=%s' % (productASIN, api.associate_tag, api.access_key, signatureTime, signature)

#Split and byte order the request (poorly but should always be the same)
parameters = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for line in url.split('&'):
    if (line.startswith('AssociateTag')):
        parameters[0] = line
    elif (line.startswith('AWSAccessKeyId')):
        parameters[1] = line
    elif (line.startswith('IdType')):
        parameters[2] = line
    elif (line.startswith('ItemId')):
        parameters[3] = line
    elif (line.startswith('Operation')):
        parameters[4] = line
    elif (line.startswith('ResponseGroup')):
        parameters[5] = line
    elif (line.startswith('Timestamp')):
        parameters[6] = line
rejoined = ''
i = 1
for line in parameters:
    if i < len(parameters):
        rejoined += line + '&'
    else:
        rejoined += line
    i += 1
print 'Rejoined: ' + rejoined

# Prepend the request beginning
prepend = 'GET\nwebservices.amazon.com\n/onca/xml\n' + rejoined
print 'Prepend: ' + prepend

# HMAC with SHA256 hash algorithm
dig = hmac.new(api.access_key, msg=prepend, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
signature = base64.b64encode(dig).decode()      # py3k-mode
print 'Signature: ' + signature
encodedSignature = urllib.quote_plus(signature)     # encode the signature
print 'Encoded Signature: ' + encodedSignature
finalRequest = 'http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?' + rejoined + '&Signature=' + encodedSignature

# Final request to send
print 'URL: ' + finalRequest

# Use BeautifulSoup to create the html
r = requests.get(finalRequest)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print soup.prettify()
```

Here's the response:

```
Apple iPhone 5s, Gold 16GB (Unlocked): B00F3J4E5U
-------------------------------------------------
Rejoined: AssociateTag=dperkgithu-20&AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&IdType=ASIN&ItemId=B00F3J4E5U&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Reviews&Timestamp=2014-10-01T19%3A36%3A41Z
Prepend: GET
webservices.amazon.com
/onca/xml
AssociateTag=dperkgithu-20&AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&IdType=ASIN&ItemId=B00F3J4E5U&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Reviews&Timestamp=2014-10-01T19%3A36%3A41Z
Signature: YAeIaDuigxbTX7AoZzRreZzn//RbIucCiwsG9VqMayQ=
Encoded Signature: YAeIaDuigxbTX7AoZzRreZzn%2F%2FRbIucCiwsG9VqMayQ%3D
URL: http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?AssociateTag=dperkgithu-20&AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&IdType=ASIN&ItemId=B00F3J4E5U&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Reviews&Timestamp=2014-10-01T19%3A36%3A41Z&Signature=YAeIaDuigxbTX7AoZzRreZzn%2F%2FRbIucCiwsG9VqMayQ%3D
<html>
 <body>
  <itemlookuperrorresponse xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
   <error>
    <code>
     SignatureDoesNotMatch
    </code>
    <message>
     The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
    </message>
   </error>
   <requestid>
    c159b688-9b08-4cc9-94fe-35245aa69cc9
   </requestid>
  </itemlookuperrorresponse>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why aren't you using boto for this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you can pull product information (such as reviews) or do the REST request that I'm trying to do with boto. If I'm wrong please correct me.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with it, but it seems to support a lot of AWS services: https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/ And I know it does REST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a successful request to the Amazon Product Advertising API. If you want to have a peek at the returned XML, use the product object.

As for you reviews, they are no longer available as plain text via the API. You would need to scrape HTML from Amazon.com directly.

Comment: Thanks, yea took me a while to figure it out after I had posted this but I was doing it correctly. Ended up doing exactly what you said and just parsing.